# How can I reproduce this table with thick lines?

Tags: tables, rules

I'm trying to reproduce this table:

[image: table with thick first vertical and horizontal lines]

(apologies for the terrible cameraphone pic)

I don't know how to get the slightly thicker leftmost and topmost line.

Here's a minimal example of what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
    $*$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ \\\hline
    $a$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $b$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $b$ & $b$ & $c$ & $a$ & $e$ & $c$ \\\hline
    $c$ & $c$ & $a$ & $b$ & $b$ & $a$ \\\hline
    $d$ & $b$ & $e$ & $b$ & $e$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $e$ & $d$ & $b$ & $a$ & $d$ & $c$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way to make the leftmost and topmost lines thicker?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You could define a thick version of `\hline` and a thick `|` as new column type as I did below. Both are based on the original code, only the thickness got changed from `\arrayrulewidth` to `1pt`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thickhline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\newcolumntype{"}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c"c|c|c|c|c}
    $*$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ \\\thickhline
    $a$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $b$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $b$ & $b$ & $c$ & $a$ & $e$ & $c$ \\\hline
    $c$ & $c$ & $a$ & $b$ & $b$ & $a$ \\\hline
    $d$ & $b$ & $e$ & $b$ & $e$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $e$ & $d$ & $b$ & $a$ & $d$ & $c$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

On request here a definition of a thick version of `\cline`:

```
\newcommand{\thickcline}[1]{%
    \@thickcline #1\@nil%
}

\def\@thickcline#1-#2\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height1pt\hfill
  \cr
  \noalign{\vskip-1pt}%
}
```

Comment: I truly love this answer, however, what if I want a thick line but from certain position on the table to another one (not coordinates, good idea anyway) like the usage of `cline`.

Comment: I mean partial horizontal thick lines.

Comment: @Hans: I added a definition for a `\thickcline` now. Note that if you mix it with normal `\cline` or `\hline` the lines will be top aligned, which doesn't look that good.

Comment: I'd really like to use this, but when I do there is a gap between the *leftmost* line and the left edge of the table and the *rightmost* line and the right edge of the table so the top line overhangs the lines going down and this looks terrible. What do I do to fix that?

Comment: @MartinScharrer Your definition of `"` gives me display problems when I try to place it as the left and right edge lines, e.g. `\begin{tabular}{"c"c"} ...` will make the horizontal lines go beyond the vertical ones at the edges. I made the following modification: `\newcolumntype{[}{@{\vrule width 1pt\hspace{6pt}}}
\newcolumntype{]}{@{\hspace{6pt}\vrule width 1pt}}
\newcolumntype{!}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule width 1pt\hskip\tabcolsep}}` which seems to get rid of the problem used as `\begin{tabular}{[c!c]} ...`. My `!` is the same as your `"`: for people using Kile the latter might be annoying.

Comment: how do i adapt this to work with arrays in math mode?

Answer (score 61):

The package [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) provides such a modification by the optional arguments of the vertical line and the command `\tabucline`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{c|[2pt]c|c|c|c|c}
    $*$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ \\\tabucline[2pt]{-}
    $a$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $b$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $b$ & $b$ & $c$ & $a$ & $e$ & $c$ \\\hline
    $c$ & $c$ & $a$ & $b$ & $b$ & $a$ \\\hline
    $d$ & $b$ & $e$ & $b$ & $e$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $e$ & $d$ & $b$ & $a$ & $d$ & $c$
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*However to produce nice tables avoid vertical lines and be spare with horizontal lines. For all this I recommend the package booktabs. Via google you will find a lot of examples.*

Comment: Thank you for the super-fast and cogent response. I'm going to be typesetting a fair number of these tables which define binary operations on finite sets. Can you elaborate on how you think the appearance could be improved? Should this be a separate question?

Comment: This is possibly one case where rules may remain, as it's really a lattice and not a formal table. But I would avoid thick rules anyway.

Comment: @Harold: My note depends on normal tables. For your binary tables I would work in the same way but I would also increase the space between the cells.

Comment: Dear @MarcoDaniel, how can I color one table box in tabu environment?
Thanks for help,
R.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical `{tabular}` (of `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use those nodes to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz in the `\CodeAfter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{cccccc}[hvlines-except-borders]
    * & a & b & c & d & e \\
    a & a & b & c & b & d \\
    b & b & c & a & e & c \\
    c & c & a & b & b & a \\
    d & b & e & b & e & d \\
    e & d & b & a & d & c
\CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [thick, line cap = round] (2-|1) -- (2-|last) (1-|2) -- (last-|2) ; 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the first code]

With recent version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.11 of 2022-07-16), it's also possible to define a command (for horizontal rules) and a letter (for vertical rules) with any Tikz charateristic wished.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    custom-line = 
     {
       letter = I , % for the vertical rules
       command = boldhline , % the horizontal rules 
       total-width = 1 pt , 
       tikz = { line width = 1 pt } 
     }
  }

\begin{NiceTabular}{cIc|c|c|c|c}
    $*$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $e$ \\\boldhline
    $a$ & $a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $b$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $b$ & $b$ & $c$ & $a$ & $e$ & $c$ \\\hline
    $c$ & $c$ & $a$ & $b$ & $b$ & $a$ \\\hline
    $d$ & $b$ & $e$ & $b$ & $e$ & $d$ \\\hline
    $e$ & $d$ & $b$ & $a$ & $d$ & $c$
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

The output is not exactly the same, because, now, a space is reserved for the width of the rules (both horizontally and vertically).

[image]