# Change border of a few cells in a table

Tags: tables

Let's say I have a table with 4 columns and 8 rows.  The top row is the label for each of the rows below.  Suppose I want the cell borders for rows 4 and 5 to be thicker than the rest of the cells in the table.  Is there a way to accomplish this in LaTeX?

```
\begin{table*}[ht]
{\normalsize
\hfill{}
\large
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \bf ID & \bf Raw Score & \bf Num & \bf Total Hits & \bf Avg \\ 
\hline 217842950 & 8282 & 9 & 10059 & 0.176658 \\ 
\hline 264307945 & 7700 & 13 & 11076 & 0.304803 \\ 
\hline 111824111 & 6170 & 16 & 9467 & 0.348262 \\ 
\hline 331180650 & 1705 & 31 & 2668 & 0.360945 \\ 
\hline 436114131 & 1540 & 6 & 1773 & 0.131416 \\ 
\hline 546694115 & 1460 & 6 & 1685 & 0.133531 \\ 
\hline 467026458 & 1058 & 36 & 1237 & 0.144705 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} }
\hfill{}
\caption{Scores for the top-7 IDs .}
\label{tb:tablename}
\end{table*}
```

Above is the table I have.  I'm unsure how I would even go about changing the border around any row (or cell)

Comment: Can you show some minimal code that you tried so far. It will save us from some extra typing and guessing work.

Comment: Thick lines are covered in [How can I reproduce this table with thick lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41758/how-can-i-reproduce-this-table-with-thick-lines).

Comment: You can use the method I described in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here you have a simple example; the idea is to use `\noalign{\hrule height <length>}` instead of `\hline` to get a horixontal rule of thickness given by `<length>`; for a vertical rule, not spanning the whole table, the idea is to use \multicolumn and in the second argument to use `!{\vrule width <length>}` instead of `|` to get a vertical rule of thickness given by `<length>` for that cell (the `array` package is required for this last construction):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
column1a & column2a \\
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{column1b} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{column2b} \\
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
column1c & column2c \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's an example with your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table*}
{\normalsize
\hfill{}
\large
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \bf ID & \bf Raw Score & \bf Num & \bf Total Hits & \bf Avg \\ 
\hline 217842950 & 8282 & 9 & 10059 & 0.176658 \\ 
\hline 264307945 & 7700 & 13 & 11076 & 0.304803 \\ 
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{111824111} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{6170} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{16} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{9467} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{0.348262} \\ 
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
\multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{331180650} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{1705} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{31} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{2668} & 
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 1pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{0.360945} \\ 
\noalign{\hrule height 2pt}
 436114131 & 1540 & 6 & 1773 & 0.131416 \\ 
\hline 546694115 & 1460 & 6 & 1685 & 0.133531 \\ 
\hline 467026458 & 1058 & 36 & 1237 & 0.144705 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} }
\hfill{}
\caption{Scores for the top-7 IDs .}
\label{tb:tablename}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can define macros such as:

```
\newcommand\Thickvrule[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 1pt}}{#1}%
}
```

and then use

```
\Thickvrule{6170}
```

in your document.

For just some cells, a variant of `\cline` with the desired thickness can be defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength\Origarrayrulewidth
\newcommand{\Cline}[1]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength\Origarrayrulewidth{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}}\cline{#1}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{\Origarrayrulewidth}}%
}

\newcommand\Thickvrule[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\large
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \bf ID & \bf Raw Score & \bf Num & \bf Total Hits & \bf Avg \\ 
\hline 217842950 & 8282 & 9 & 10059 & 0.176658 \\ 
\Cline{1-1}\cline{2-5} 
\Thickvrule{264307945} & 7700 & 13 & 11076 & 0.304803 \\ 
\Cline{1-1}\cline{2-4}\Cline{4-4}\cline{4-5}
111824111 & 6170 & 16 & \Thickvrule{9467} & 0.348262 \\ 
\cline{1-4}\Cline{4-4}\cline{4-5}
331180650 & 1705 & 31 & 2668 & 0.360945 \\ 
\hline 436114131 & 1540 & 6 & 1773 & 0.131416 \\ 
\cline{1-2}\Cline{2-2}\cline{3-5}
546694115 & \Thickvrule{1460} & 6 & 1685 & 0.133531 \\ 
\cline{1-2}\Cline{2-2}\cline{3-5}
467026458 & 1058 & 36 & 1237 & 0.144705 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Scores for the top-7 IDs .}
\label{tb:tablename}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
And some other macros for the case of more than one cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newlength\Origarrayrulewidth

% horizontal rule equivalent to \cline but with 2pt width
\newcommand{\Cline}[1]{%
 \noalign{\global\setlength\Origarrayrulewidth{\arrayrulewidth}}%
 \noalign{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}}\cline{#1}%
 \noalign{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{\Origarrayrulewidth}}%
}

% draw a vertical rule of width 2pt on both sides of a cell
\newcommand\Thickvrule[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{#1}%
}

% draw a vertical rule of width 2pt on the left side of a cell
\newcommand\Thickvrulel[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c|}{#1}%
}

% draw a vertical rule of width 2pt on the right side of a cell
\newcommand\Thickvruler[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{#1}%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{table*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\centering
\large
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \bf ID & \bf Raw Score & \bf Num & \bf Total Hits & \bf Avg \\ 
\hline 217842950 & 8282 & 9 & 10059 & 0.176658 \\ 
\Cline{1-1}\cline{2-5} 
\Thickvrule{264307945} & 7700 & 13 & 11076 & 0.304803 \\ 
\Cline{1-1}\cline{2-4}\Cline{4-4}\cline{4-5}
111824111 & 6170 & 16 & \Thickvrule{9467} & 0.348262 \\ 
\cline{1-4}\Cline{4-4}\cline{4-5}
331180650 & 1705 & 31 & 2668 & 0.360945 \\ 
\cline{1-2}\Cline{2-2}\cline{3-5}
436114131 & \Thickvrule{1540} & 6 & 1773 & 0.131416 \\ 
\cline{1-2}\Cline{2-2}\cline{3-5}
546694115 & 1460 & 6 & 1685 & 0.133531 \\
\Cline{1-5} 
\Thickvrulel{467026458} & 1058 & 36 & 1237 & \Thickvruler{0.144705} \\ 
\Cline{1-5} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Scores for the top-7 IDs .}
\label{tb:tablename}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, as a side note, you should consider not using vertical rules in your tables (this is only a suggestion, of course); with the help of the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package you can easily produce beautiful tables.

Comment: oh, those last two examples really need a bit more "air" above the contents of the cells; the thick rules are touching, or even slightly overprinting, the digits.  it would also be more attractive (though more complicated) to divide the thickness of the horizontal rules between the cells above and below; this is most obvious when the rule doesn't extend across the entire table.

Comment: @barbarabeeton right again ;-) I added some extra vertical space to the rows. I'll prepare an example using you other suggestion (the one about dividing the thickness of the rule).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  One last thing though, how does one center the above table in the document?

Comment: @ngramsky: use `\centering` right after the `\begin{table*}` line; I'll add it to my code.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a rant rather than an answer.

I do wish LaTeX had a table mechanism that separated content from presentation. For example, this is how one would achieve the same effect in ConTeXt:

```
\startsetups table:highlight
  \setupTABLE[each][each][align=middle,loffset=2pt, roffset=2pt]
  \setupTABLE[row][first][style=bold]
  \setupTABLE[row][3,4]  [rulethickness=2pt]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=table:highlight]
  \NC ID        \NC Raw Score \NC Num \NC Total Hits \NC    Avg   \NC \NR
  \NC 217842950 \NC 8282      \NC   9 \NC      10059 \NC 0.176658 \NC \NR 
  \NC 264307945 \NC 7700      \NC  13 \NC      11076 \NC 0.304803 \NC \NR
  \NC 436114131 \NC 1540      \NC   6 \NC       1773 \NC 0.131416 \NC \NR 
  \NC 546694115 \NC 1460      \NC   6 \NC       1685 \NC 0.133531 \NC \NR 
  \NC 467026458 \NC 1058      \NC  36 \NC       1237 \NC 0.144705 \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

Behind the scenes, ConTeXt is doing something similar to Gonzalo Medina's solution. But it provides a nice key-value driven interface that hides the details from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Using the package `nicematrix`, you can define the following new command `\Frame`:

`\NewDocumentCommand{\Frame}{}{\Block[draw , line-width=2pt]{1-1}{}}`

Then use it at a cell within a `NiceTabular` environment:

`\Frame{cell content}`

Answer (score 0):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In that environment, the built-in command `\Block` is used to merge cells and format the resulting rectangle. However, it's possible to use it with one cell.

That's what we do by using its key `tikz`. Each time that key is used, the rectangle of the cell is used in Tikz with the keys provided as argument to `tikz`.

With `tikz=clip`, we clip to the rectangle of the cell.

With `tikz={draw,line width=2pt}`, we draw the frame.

We have written a command `\Frame` which does the job.

The built-in command `\RowStyle` (of `nicematrix`) applies its argument to each cell of the row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Frame}{}{\Block[tikz={draw,offset=0.5pt,line width= 1pt}]{1-1}{}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
ID & Raw Score & Num & Total Hits & Avg \\ 
217842950 & 8282 & 9 & 10059 & 0.176658 \\ 
\Frame 264307945 & 7700 & 13 & 11076 & 0.304803 \\ 
111824111 & 6170 & 16 & 9467 & 0.348262 \\ 
331180650 & 1705 & 31 & 2668 & 0.360945 \\ 
\RowStyle{\Frame}
436114131 & 1540 & 6 & 1773 & 0.131416 \\ 
546694115 & 1460 & 6 & 1685 & 0.133531 \\ 
467026458 & 1058 & 36 & 1237 & 0.144705 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular} 

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]