# pdfpages doesn't allow me to draw a thick horizontal line in "tabular"

Tags: tables, rules, pdfpages

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption,sansmath}
\usepackage{array}
\DeclareCaptionFont{sansmath}{\sansmath}
\captionsetup{textfont={sf,sansmath}}

\newlength\Origarrayrulewidth

% horizontal rule equivalent to \cline but with 2pt width
\newcommand{\Cline}[1]{%
 \noalign{\global\setlength\Origarrayrulewidth{\arrayrulewidth}}%
 \noalign{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}}\cline{#1}%
 \noalign{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{\Origarrayrulewidth}}%
}

% draw a vertical rule of width 2pt on both sides of a cell
\newcommand\Thickvrule[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{#1}%
}

% draw a vertical rule of width 2pt on the left side of a cell
\newcommand\Thickvrulel[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c|}{#1}%
}

% draw a vertical rule of width 2pt on the right side of a cell
\newcommand\Thickvruler[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{#1}%
}

% Square cells in the matrix, so we just increase the space between rows
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c |c|c|c|c|c|}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_{1}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_{3}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_{4}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c_{5}$} \\ \cline{2-6}
            $r_{1}$ & 2     & 8     & 4     & 5     & 3     \\ \cline{2-6}
            $r_{2}$ & 4       & 9     & 6     & 7     & 1     \\ \cline{2-6}
            $r_{3}$ & 3       & 4     & 2     & 0     & 9     \\ \cline{2-6}
            $r_{4}$ & 1       & 0     & 9     & 8     & 4     \\ \cline{2-6}
            $r_{5}$ & 8       & 3     & 7     & 6     & 5     \\ \cline{2-6}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}
    }
    \hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c |c|c|c|c|c|}
           \multicolumn{1}{c}{~} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} \\ \Cline{2-2}\cline{2-6}
           1 & \Thickvrule{\hspace{0.8em}}       & \hspace{0.8em}     & \hspace{0.8em}     & \hspace{0.8em}     & \hspace{0.8em}     \\ \Cline{2-3}\cline{3-6}
           2 &  \hspace{0.8em}  & \Thickvrule{~}    & \hspace{0.8em}    & \hspace{0.8em}     &\hspace{0.8em}     \\ \cline{2-3}\Cline{3-4}\cline{4-6}
           3 & \hspace{0.8em}       & \hspace{0.8em}     & \Thickvrule{\hspace{0.8em}}     & \hspace{0.8em}     & \hspace{0.8em}     \\ \cline{2-4}\Cline{4-5}\cline{6-6}
           4 & \hspace{0.8em}       & \hspace{0.8em}    & \hspace{0.8em}     & \Thickvrule{\hspace{0.8em}}     & \hspace{0.8em}     \\ \cline{2-5}\Cline{5-6}
           5 & \hspace{0.8em}      & \hspace{0.8em}     & \hspace{0.8em}    & \hspace{0.8em}     & \Thickvrule{\hspace{0.8em}}     \\ \cline{2-6}\Cline{6-6}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This code was copied from here:

[Change border of a few cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56987/change-border-of-a-few-cells-in-a-table)

The code is correct. When I am trying to use the `pdfpages` package, the thick horizontal line is not shown. Could you please answer what is the reason? When I remove this package, the line is shown successfully. I have a lot of matrices in the article, I can't remove them or rewrite, but also I must add an appendix at the end of the document.

After redefining \setlength I have the error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.1584 \includepdf[pages=-]{nosingl1.pdf}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   (
l.1584 \includepdf[pages=-]{nosingl1.pdf}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

If I don't redefine it, the code is compiled successfully, that is the compilation error occurs when I am including a pdf file:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{nosingl1.pdf}
\includepdf[angle=90]{nosingl2.pdf}
\includepdf[angle=90]{nosingl3.pdf}
```

Comment: Your statement, "When I'm trying to use the `pdfpages` package, ..." is ambiguous: Are you trying to include the output of the current MWE in some other file and that's when the problem occurs, or does the mere loading of the `pdfpages` document in the current document cause the problem behavior? Please elaborate.

Comment: I just declare \usepackage{pdfpages} and want to include some pdf files: \includepdf{1.pdf}. The line is not shown, even when I don't try to include smth, just declare this package.

Comment: It's a (bad?) side effect of `texpower` package which is required by `pdfpages` package. Just add `\usepackage{texpower}` and you get the same effect (`\Cline` don't produce thick rule).

Comment: @PolGab: [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) doesn't load [`texpower`](http://ctan.org/pkg/texpower)... well, not in version 2012/04/03 v0.4s.

Comment: @Werner Exact... It's a (bad?) side effect of `calc` package which is required by `pdfpages` package. Just add `\usepackage{calc}` and you get the same effect (`\Cline` don't produce thick rule). `calc` redefines `\setlength`.

Comment: neither \usepackage{calc} nor \usepackage{texpower} has helped. I can't see \Cline.

Answer (score 2):

Using the TeX-style length settings seems to circumvent the problem, otherwise the length settings remain local:

[image]

```
% horizontal rule equivalent to \cline but with 2pt width
\newcommand{\Cline}[1]{%
  \noalign{\global\Origarrayrulewidth\arrayrulewidth%
    \global\arrayrulewidth2pt}\cline{#1}%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\Origarrayrulewidth}%
}
```

As mentioned by PolGab in comment, this interaction results from [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) (loaded by [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)) redefining `\setlength`. Restoring the original `\setlength` command (*after* loading `pdfpages` or `calc`) to

```
\def\setlength#1#2{#1#2\relax}%
```

also solves this problem. Not sure about other side-effects though.

Comment: Is there an error in your code? After your redefining I have the error. See the updated question

Comment: @user565447: Have you tried the version of `\Cline` in my answer rather than a redefinition of `\setlength`?

Comment: yes, I have. There is no result

Comment: See the updated question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mainly that

```
\global\setlength
```

is *not* officially supported by LaTeX and, in fact, `calc` redefines `setlength` in a way that makes `\global\setlength` completely ineffective, as it applies `\global` to a temporary variable (precisely it does `\global\let\calc@A #1`, where `#1` is the argument to `\setlength`).

Simply write

```
\newcommand{\Cline}[1]{%
 \noalign{\xdef\Origarrayrulewidth{\the\arrayrulewidth}}%
 \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=2pt}\cline{#1}%
 \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=\Origarrayrulewidth}%
}
```

which also avoids allocating `\Origarrayrulewidth` as dimension.

Redefining `\setlength` after having loaded `pdfpages` is of course *not* recommendable, as this package *does* rely on `\setlength` as defined by `calc`.

Comment: it doesn't help. I have the compilation error