# Drawing a zig-zag line within table similar to that of the periodic table

Tags: tables

I have searched quite a bit for something related to what I am trying to create. I am trying to replicate a table with a zig-zag line such as that of the periodic table. I managed to define a new Cline thickness, however that merely draws the thick horizontal line beneath a certain or some cells. I am struggling the draw the thick vertical lines. I have read about multicolumn definitions but do not know if this is merely the approach to follow or if there is a quicker way. In short i just want to add a thick zig-zag line to a table such as that of the periodic table. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Not an answer to your question - just a comment. You may consider producing the table as a graphics, e.g. using the TikZ package. This allows much more variability than a standard table. For example, see the [periodic table using TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/). Of course, it depends on what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I'd consider a matrix of nodes from tikz

Comment: Could you show us a sample table? It'll help to shape answers....

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a *thick* separation line in a tabular environment like so:

[image]

Maybe this Questions may help you:

- [pdfpages doesn't allow me to draw a thick horizontal line in "tabular"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61056/101053)
- [Change border of a few cells in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56987/101053)
- [How can I reproduce this table with thick lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41758/101053)
- [Nice-looking tables with thick rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98468/101053)

It would really help to know what this is for. `Tikz` is an **easy way** for making complex drawings like a periodic table (at least in comparison to `Tabular` :P).