# Nice-looking tables with thick rules

Tags: tables, rules

I want to make a table with rules that are thicker than the default.  It's pretty straightforward to do, however the result looks bad: the lines have gaps in them (see image below).  There must be a way to make this look better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    hello & world \cr
    \hline
    hello & world \cr
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: You might want to have a look at [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/). It's a package designed to make nice tables.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41758/how-can-i-reproduce-this-table-with-thick-lines/41759#41759

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{array}`. However, in general, vertical lines in tables are frowned upon and you should use them only if there's a good reason for it. As well, in LaTeX `tabular`-like environments, the macro `\\` is prefered over `\cr`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    hello & world \\
    \hline
    hello & world \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```