# How do I make a TikZ matrix match height?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to make a table using the matrix TikZlibrary. The problem is that the height does not match. [image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (M) [
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=0mm,
    row sep=0cm,
    nodes={
        draw,
        line width=1pt,
        anchor=south, 
        minimum height=8mm
    },
    column 1/.style={
        nodes={
            text width=3cm,
            minimum width=3cm,
            fill=yellow
        }
    },
    column 2/.style={
        nodes={
            text width=4cm,
            minimum width=4cm,
        }
    }
]{  
    Short text & Longer text. Spanning over several lines \\
    Short text & Another long text. Spanning over even more lines...\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `minimum height` of the `nodes` to a value that is (at least) as large as the highest node. `16mm` is sufficient for this example.

If you want different heights for different rows, you can use the `row n` styles, similar to the `column n` styles you've used in your example. For example

```
    row 1/.style={
        nodes={
           minimum height=10mm
        }
    },
```

Note that you should add these before the `column n` styles.

Another thing to note is that the lines around each cell doesn't overlap, giving lines of double width between cells. Set the `row sep` and `col sep` to `-1pt` to fix this.

You can of course use a `tabular` instead. That the lines in the table sometimes disappear is usually just a viewer issue -- the lines are there, but the coloured fields are snapped to pixel boundaries, which can cover the lines (see e.g. [Missing lines when shading cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162800/missing-lines-when-shading-cells)). If you zoom in, you'll probably see the lines, which should also appear in print.

In the below code I increased the width of the table rules a bit. (cf. [Nice-looking tables with thick rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98468/nice-looking-tables-with-thick-rules))

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\cellcolor{yellow}}m{3cm} | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash} m{4cm} |}
\hline
Short text & Longer text. Spanning over several lines \\ \hline
Short text & Another long text. Spanning over even more lines... \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (M) [
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=0mm,
    row sep=0cm,
    nodes={
        draw,
        line width=1pt,
        anchor=south, 
    },
    row 1/.style={
        nodes={
           minimum height=10mm
        }
    },
    row 2/.style={
        nodes={
           minimum height=20mm
        }
    },
    column 1/.style={
        nodes={
            text width=3cm,
            minimum width=3cm,
            fill=yellow
        }
    },
    column 2/.style={
        nodes={
            text width=4cm,
            minimum width=4cm,
        }
    }        
]{  
    Short text & Longer text. Spanning over several lines \\
    Short text & Another long text. Spanning over even more lines...\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but say I wanted to have a more arbitrary height. Is that possible?

Comment: @davidAK What do you mean by 'arbitrary'?

Comment: What I mean is that the right side column has a variable height, and I think it will look nicer when the left column matches that.

Now, I could have done this with the **tabular** environment, but the cellcolor would overwrite the black lines. So I thought I that TikZ would be a better option.

Comment: @davidAK See my updated answer. Usually a `cellcolor` does *not* overwrite the lines, it is just a viewer issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. This is exactly what I'm looking for.