# How to remove unwanted horizontal line from diagbox

Tags: tables, tabularx, diagbox

I'm using \diagbox in a table, but for some reason the horizontal line is still there. The table ends up looking like this:

[image: table]

And on another note, the vertical lines don't completely join to the top rule. Any help would be appreciated.

The code is like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox{\textbf{Model}}{\textbf{Test Data}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 0}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 1}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 2}}  &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 3}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 4}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 5}} \\ \hline
& \emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & \mu & \emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & \mu &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & \mu &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & \mu &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & \mu &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & \mu \\ \toprule
\textbf{Level 0} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 1} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 2} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 3} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 4} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 5} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages?

Answer (score 10):

In order to remove the horizontal line that goes throught the first cell in the first column, replace `\hline` by `\cline{2-19}`. Regarding the vertical lines not connecting with the horizontal line: Replace `\toprule` with `\hline`. (Lines from the `booktabs` package are not compatible with vertical lines).

For the following MWE, I have assumed, that the `?` in the table column specification are defined as follows: `\usepackage{array} \newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}` (See: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156820/134144)). However, the vertical lines don't match the screenshot in your question, so might have to change them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?c|c?c?}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\diagbox{\textbf{Model}}{\textbf{Test Data}}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 0}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 1}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 2}}  &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 3}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 4}} &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Level 5}} \\ \cline{2-19}
& \emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ & \emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ \\ \hline
\textbf{Level 0} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 1} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 2} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 3} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 4} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\textbf{Level 5} & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Personally, I would redesign your table as follows. (Note that the table is a lot narrower now and more likely to fit into the textwidth of your document).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccccccc}
\toprule
Model & \multicolumn{18}{c}{Test Data} \\ \cmidrule{2-19}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level 0} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level 1} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level 2}  &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level 3} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level 4} &  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Level 5} \\ \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}  \cmidrule(lr){8-10}  \cmidrule(lr){11-13}  \cmidrule(lr){14-16}  \cmidrule(lr){17-19}
& \emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ & \emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ &\emph{R1} & \emph{R2} & $\mu$ \\ \midrule
Level 0 & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ 
Level 1 & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ 
Level 2 & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ 
Level 3 & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ 
Level 4 & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ 
Level 5 & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & u & b & a & \emph{u} & \emph{b} & \emph{a}\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey leandriis . Thanks so much for this! I definitely prefer your layout. Thanks for all of the help and have a great day!

Comment: @Alice: Glad I was able to help you. If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).