# Thick Lines on table

Tags: tables, rules, tabularx

I've seen [the answer someone posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41761/42784) and I implemented it, I would like to keep this configuration as I already based my word using this answer.
Now, the question is, how can I make partial horizontal lines like what does `\cline{-}`.

Comment: `\cmidrule` from `booktabs` has an optional argument (if I remember well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following, we define a new version of `\cline` as `\Cline` where you can provide the required thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\Cline#1#2{\@Cline#1#2\@nil}
\def\@Cline#1-#2#3\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
  \cr}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \hline
  A & B & C\\\hline
  D & E & F\\
  \Cline{1-2}{5.0pt}
  G & H & I\\
  \Cline{1-2}{2.0pt}
  J & K & L\\
  \cline{1-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As can see, you are in control of the thickness when you use `\Cline`.

[image]

And the non-thick standard `\cline` is always there.

Should need all your `\clines` (and other lines) to be thick, change `\arrayrulewidth` to some value you wish.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but is there a way of fix the height of the cells, please have a loook at the `G` and `H` squares, the letters are almost lost.

Comment: Yes, see the updated answer.

Comment: I would like to understand all that you did, is there a book you advice me to learn all this? (btw, accepted answer).

Comment: The knowledge which played the major role was understanding LaTeX macros. I learned mine from [The TeXBook](http://www.amazon.com/TeXbook-Donald-Knuth/dp/0201134489), Chapter 20. But you can try [this one](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/courses/math696/goose-macro.html) as well. And remember, there are no quick ways, initial days have very steep curves. Sounds pedantic? Meant to be.

Answer (score 6):

The `makecell` package already has, among many other features, the `Xhline` and `\Xcline` commands. Examples of use:

```
\Xhline{1.2pt}
\Xcline{3-6}{2pt}
```

Excerpt from the doc:
[image]