# How to add an argument to a \cline-like macro?

Tags: arguments, cline, hline

I want utility macros that allow me to change (a) the thickness and/or (b) color of `\hline`s or `\cline`s in `tabular`s. I want to do so without redefining `\arrayrulewidth` but rather by modifying the existing `\hline` and `\cline` macros to use my desired thickness in place of `\arrayrulewidth`.

I first did this for `\hline` by adding an argument for the thickness of the rule to [Martin Scharrer's answer's `\thickhline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41761/7922). See `\hlineThickness` below. I completed the goal by adding a second argument for a color; see `\hlineThicknessColor` below. That worked as desired.

I hoped to do the same for `\cline`. I used [Masroor's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173535/7922) to first define `\clineThickness` with two arguments; the first for the range of columns for the `\cline` and the second for the width of the rule. `\clineThickness` invokes a macro `\@ClineThickness` with three arguments. The first argument of `\clineThickness` is apparently parsed to become two arguments, one for the initial column and one for the final column. That worked as hoped: I could vary the thickness of a black `\cline`.

Where I ran into trouble was when I tried to add a new, third argument for a color to define `\clineThicknessColor`. First, I don't know TeX at all, so I don't follow how `\cline` seems to parse the first argument (containing a range of columns) into two separate arguments.

Nevertheless, I attempted to add a third argument by simply tacking on `#3` (a) to the definition of `\clineThickness` and (b) to the invocation of `\@ClineThickness`, and adding `#4` to the definition of `\@ClineThickness`. However, without even trying to make use of the new argument, I get the error "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."

An MWE is below. Two lines are commented out. First, I commented out
`\clineThicknessColor{2-3}{1.5pt}{blue}` so that it will compile.

Second, I commented out `\leaders\color{#4}\hrule\@height#3\hfill` just to indicate how I'm planning to use the new color argument if I can first successfully add that argument.

What am I doing wrong in my attempt to add a color argument to `\clineThicknessColor`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hlineThickness}[1]{%
%   Example usage: \hlineThickness{2pt}
%   Inspired by Martin Scharrer's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41761/7922
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height #1
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\newcommand{\hlineThicknessColor}[2]{%
%   Example usage: \hlineThicknessColor{0.6pt}{red}
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \color{#2}\hrule height #1
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\def\clineThickness#1#2{\@ClineThickness#1#2\@nil}
%   Example usage: \ClineThickness{2-5}{2.0pt}
%   Source: Masroor's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173535/7922
\def\@ClineThickness#1-#2#3\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
  \cr}

\def\clineThicknessColor#1#2#3{\@ClineThicknessColor#1#2#3\@nil}
%   Example usage: \clineThicknessColor{2-3}{1.5pt}{blue}
\def\@ClineThicknessColor#1-#2#3#4\@nil{%
    \omit
    \@multicnt#1%
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
    \@multicnt#2%
    \advance\@multicnt-#1%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
%   \leaders\color{#4}\hrule\@height#3\hfill
    \cr}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c}
A & B & C & D\\
\hlineThickness{2pt}
E & F & G & H\\
\hlineThicknessColor{0.6pt}{red}
I & J & K & L\\
\clineThickness{2-3}{1.5pt}
M & N & O & P\\
%\clineThicknessColor{2-3}{1.5pt}{blue}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, you just have to rearrange the argument specification for `\@ClineThicknessColor` a little bit and put extra braces around the arguments.

Let me explain how parsing the dash in a macro works. When you define a command with `\def`, you give an argument specification which is a pattern that tex expects to see after you use the command. For example if I say `\def\test#1-#2{...}` then when I use the command `\test`, latex expects to see some number of (brace balanced) arbitrary tokens followed by a dash, followed by a dash, followed by one token or braced argument. For instance, if I then say `\test abc-def` then argument `#1` will be `abc`, argument `#2` will be `d` and `ef` will be left on the input stream. If I say `\test {abc}-{def}` then argument `#1` is `abc` and argument `#2` is `def` (note that the braces have been removed from the arguments). If I say `\test{abc-def}` then tex doesn't see the dash in the braces and keeps looking for a dash. If it doesn't find a dash it throws an error.

Thus, there is a standard trick to parse an argument like `{abc-def}`: we use the fact that braces are removed from around an argument, so I say:

```
\def\mycommand#1{\myhelpercommand#1\@nil}
\def\myhelpercommand#1-#2\@nil{...} % do stuff here
```

The point of the token \@nil is to serve as a delimiter for the second argument -- with the braces removed, tex can no longer tell where the argument ends without some token to serve as the endpoint. Now if I want to use this pattern with a multiargument command, I need to remember to replace the braces tex removes from the later arguments, and I should put them after the `\@nil`:

```
\def\mycommand#1#2#3{\myhelpercommand#1\@nil{#2}{#3}}
\def\myhelpercommand#1-#2\@nil#3#4{...} % do stuff here
```

Here's the code with this fix added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hlineThickness}[1]{%
%   Example usage: \hlineThickness{2pt}
%   Inspired by Martin Scharrer's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41761/7922
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height #1
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\newcommand{\hlineThicknessColor}[2]{%
%   Example usage: \hlineThicknessColor{0.6pt}{red}
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \color{#2}\hrule height #1
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}

\def\clineThickness#1#2{\@ClineThickness#1#2\@nil}
%   Example usage: \ClineThickness{2-5}{2.0pt}
%   Source: Masroor's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173535/7922
\def\@ClineThickness#1-#2#3\@nil{%
  \omit
  \@multicnt#1%
  \advance\@multispan\m@ne
  \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
  \@multicnt#2%
  \advance\@multicnt-#1%
  \advance\@multispan\@ne
  \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
  \cr}

\def\clineThicknessColor#1#2#3{\@ClineThicknessColor#1\@nil{#2}{#3}}
%   Example usage: \clineThicknessColor{2-3}{1.5pt}{blue}
\def\@ClineThicknessColor#1-#2\@nil#3#4{%
    \omit
    \@multicnt#1%
    \advance\@multispan\m@ne
    \ifnum\@multicnt=\@ne\@firstofone{&\omit}\fi
    \@multicnt#2%
    \advance\@multicnt-#1%
    \advance\@multispan\@ne
    \color{#4}
    \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
    \leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill
    \cr}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c | c}
A & B & C & D\\
\hlineThickness{2pt}
E & F & G & H\\
\hlineThicknessColor{0.6pt}{red}
I & J & K & L\\
\clineThickness{2-3}{1.5pt}
M & N & O & P\\
\clineThicknessColor{2-4}{1.5pt}{blue}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea what `\@nil` accomplishes or how you knew to move it around, but I appreciate your providing the correct magical incantation! (My next commented line doesn't work, but that'll be the subject of a separate question.)

Comment: I'm working on an explanation which should clarify.

Comment: Correction: You also fixed my incorrect use of `\color`, so I don't need a new question either. Double thanks!

Comment: You could upvote my answer =P

Comment: Your additional commentary/explanation is very helpful. (But it's still seems like magic!)

Comment: I discovered soon after, with [help from David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447705/7922) that there should be braces enclosing {\color{#4}\leaders\hrule\@height#3\hfill} to prevent an extra line when used after the last row of a tabular.